# Get Menu items in content zone in orchard cms

Tags: model-view-controller, orchardcms-1.10

I have created one Content type called "Product", Then created one query that select all product and shows on home page. To show products on home page i have created projection widget.

Now when i click on particular product it gets redirect to the detail page of that product.

Question is i want to show Menu items (like navigation bar) beside the content.

in the attached image red portion will have menu items.
so how can i achieve this?

Please help.

[image]